# Categories or Custom Post Type to Organize Content

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

Let's say I'm starting a martial arts website and I want to categorize content into themes:

1. philosophy
2. fitness
3. training
4. techniques
5. diet

Etc.

I keep going back and forth between using custom loops to display the content or making each a custom post type.

Is there advantages to either?  And is it worth the trouble of creating the custom post types?

I know this is sort of a philosophical question, but was wondering if there are any solid reasons I can't think of to go either way.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to stay as close as possible to the built-in functions and behavior. I would just use tags or categories in your case. You can make both more special and rename them to *type* (for tutorials, link lists, rants etc.) and *topic*:

[image]

Questions to ask before you decide about implementation:

- What kind of relationship will I need?

  - 1:1 or 1:n (one to many) – post meta data
  - n:m (many to many) – taxonomy
  - maybe both: custom post type
- How should my permalinks look like?
- Will I need a custom edit screen?
- Will I need a separate search function?

The more extra functionality you add the harder may it be for your visitors to predict the location of your content.